# Nomen-Verb Verbindung mit Akkusativ oder Dativ

Tags: grammatical-case

The verb fallen usually takes the dative as in

> Es fällt mir schwer.

However whilst learning some noun-verb combinations I noticed that, for example,

> Wir müssen eine Entscheidung fällen

uses the accusative (or nominative).

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to English the intransitive verb (schwer-) *[fallen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/fallen:V:sein)* (to fall) also has a transitive form *[fällen](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/f%C3%A4llen:V:haben)* (to fell sth = to make sth fall) which then will take an accusative case:

> - **fällen:** Der Förster fällt den Baum (*acc*). Wir fällen eine Entscheidung (*acc*).
> - **fallen:** Der Föster (*nom*) fällt zu Boden (*dat*). Die Entscheidung (*nom*) fällt morgen.

The confusion may come from verb declension where both verbs have an identical form in the second and third person singular (see links to the verbs above).

---

Because it was asked for in a comment:

The composite separable verb [*schwerfallen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schwerfallen) is derived from [schwer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schwer) (*heavy*) and [fallen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fallen) (*to fall*). But of course it is nonesense to translate this literally. The appropriate English translation depends a bit on the context. In the example given it would be

> Es fällt mir schwer - *it is hard for me*

There are many composites using [fallen](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/fallen:V:sein) but only *ausfällen* (*chemistry*) is a composite with *fällen*.

Comment: Im Zusammenhang mit Entscheidungen ist eigentlich nicht das _Fällen_ im Sinne von _zu Fall bringen_ wie bei Bäumen gemeint, sondern das _Fällen_ im Sinne von _abfällen_, _absondern_ oder _abscheiden_ wie bei chemischen Substanzen. An der Etymologie beim Verb _entscheiden_ sieht man das auch: ent**scheiden** -> ab**scheiden** -> absondern (vgl. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidung#Etymologie). Die Entscheidung wird also sinnbildlich von der Menge der Möglichkeiten abgesondert und "fällt dann heraus", genauso wie das Präzipitat bei der Fällung aus einer Lösung abgesondert wird.

Comment: Das Verb *schwerfallen*, nach dem der Fragesteller gefragt hat, kommt in deiner Antwort nicht wirklich vor. *Schwerfallen* mit *to fall* zu übersetzen ist schlichtweg falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: kommt es jetzt deutlich genug vor?

Answer (score 5):

This is, because *»schwerfallen«* and *»fällen«* are two different verbs.

### [schwerfallen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schwerfallen)

Etwas fällt jemandem schwer = Something is difficult for somebody.

This is a separable verb. Its infinitive form (the "dictionary form") is *»schwerfallen«*, you use this form in *Futur I*:

> Die Arbeit wird mir schwerfallen.
>   Die Tätigkeiten werden mir schwerfallen.
>   Du wirst mit schwerfallen.

In *Gegenwart* the verb splits up in two components, where the former first part moves to the end of the sentence, and the former second part is inflected according to person and number of the subject:

> Die Arbeit fällt mir schwer.
>   Die Tätigkeiten fallen mir schwer.
>   Du fällst mir schwer.

---

### [fällen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/f%C3%A4llen)

einen Baum fällen = to fell/chop a tree.
eine Entscheidung fällen = to make a decision.

This is a nonseparable verb. And again you find its "dictionary form" (the infinitive form) in *Futur I*:

> Ich werde eine Entscheidung fällen.
>   Wir werden eine Entscheidung fällen.
>   Du wirst eine Entscheidung fällen.

In *Gegenwart* nothing is split away, the hole verb is inflected:

> Ich fälle eine Entscheidung.
>   Wir fällen eine Entscheidung.
>   Du fällst eine Entscheidung.

---

There also is the verb

### [fallen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/fallen)

fallen = to fall.

Futur I:

> Ich werde fallen.
>   Wir werden fallen.
>   Du wirst fallen.

Gegenwart:

> Ich falle.
>   Wir fallen.
>   Du fällst.

Comment: **a)** Ich habe den Futur I gewählt, weil das die gängigste Zeitform ist, in der trennbare Verben im Infinitv (und somit zusammengesetzt) verwendet werden. **b)** Damit meine ich, dass es ein nichttrennbares Verb ist, im Gegensatz zu schwerfallen. **c)** Das ist deine persönliche Meinung, die sich nicht mit meiner deckt. **d)** Das hielt ich nicht für notwendig, weil das nicht das Thema der Frage war. **e)** Stimmt. Ganz genau wie auch in deiner eigenen Antwort, wo du anfangs sogar nur das Verb *fallen* behandelt hast.

Answer (score 3):

(Proto-)German used to have a verb modus called the *Kausativ* which more or less meant a verb form that translated to "to make something do something". This is today frozen in the language and can no longer be used to form new verb forms, the verbs using the *Kausativ*, however, continue to exist as stand-alone, separate verbs. Some examples:

*fallen* -> to fall, *fällen* -> to make something fall

*fließen* -> to flow, *(ein)flößen* -> to make something flow (in)

*(er)saufen* -> to drown, *(er)säufen* -> to make something drown

*sinken* -> to sink, *senken* -> to make something sink

... and lots more.

Due to common ancestry, some of these are present in English today as well. Because these verbs originally were declensions of the original verbs, they often share declensions between them and are thus hard to distinguish.

In your examples, you simply fell over this hurdle. What you are comparing, are different verbs today as pointed out in other answers.

With regards to your problems with dative and accusative:

Beyond the fact that there are verbs in German that rule a certain case, nearly any verb ***can*** take the dative as this is a specific form of "do that for me".

- *fäll mir den Baum* ("cut that tree for me")
- *fall' mir nicht auf die Nerven* ("don't grate on my nerves")
- *es fällt mir schwer,...* ("I find it difficult")

This form of dative shows up for various purposes. You might want to look up concepts like *dativus possessivus*, *dativus ethicus*, *dativus commodi* and *dativus iudicantis*. "Es fällt mir schwer" is built using the *dativus iudicantis*.